# Curl returns blank page on specific port

Tags: curl, port

I am trying to get curl to output. It's a basic text string that gets outputted at that address.

I am doing this code and it's not working but works fine if i take out the 27017 and load the main domain:

```
$cookie_file_path = "cookiejar.txt"; 
$fp = fopen("$cookie_file_path","w");
fclose($fp);
$LOGINURL = "http://www.myserver.org:27017";
$agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$LOGINURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
    $result = curl_exec ($ch);
echo $result;
```

Any idea why it's not working? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Not sure if it's relevant, but the web server is running on the same machine as the app that outputs on the 27017 port.

Update:

```
$cookie_file_path = "cookiejar.txt"; 
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";
$LOGINURL = "http://www.myserver.org";
$agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$LOGINURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , "27017");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
    $result = curl_exec ($ch);

echo $result;
```

UPDATE 2:

Resolved.

Turns out it requires digest auth for this particular instance.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
```

solved the issue...

Thanks Barmar for making me realize it does indeed need a user/pass.

Answer (score 0):

When I click on the link I get asked for a username and password. You need to use the `CURLOPT_USERPWD` option to supply this:

```
$username = 'XXX';
$password = 'YYY';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
```

Here's the result I get when I do:

```
$ curl -s -D/dev/stdout 'http://www.nationalgaming.org:27017'
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 0
WWW-Authenticate: Digest qop="auth", realm="www.nationalgaming.org", nonce="1354591712"
```

This indicates that the page requires a login.

Comment: Well if you ask for index.html it will ask for a password (takes you to a different page that manages the server). However, if you DO access it directly without specifying the index.html part (just the root domain), it should not ask for a password. At least it never asked me while using chrome or ie9. Or maybe chrome/ie9 automatically specify some sort of default guest username and password.

Comment: I just clicked on the link you put in your question, it doesn't say `index.html`. Browsers optionally remember login info, so you probably have it saved in your browser.

Comment: That's not it. I tired from different machines, closed browsers, cleared all cookies/history/etc., restarted machines, and so on. It ONLY asks for user/pass when accessing /index.html. See this  [link](http://www.unknownworlds.com/ns2/wiki/index.php/Dedicated_Server#Web_API)

Comment: See my sample output from `curl` that supports what I said.

Comment: This is driving me nuts. I updated original post - see new code. But still blank page.

Comment: well i tried it from my phone and it now asks for password (maybe since it's a different IP?? who knows...) Yeah, i take it back, you were right. But i still don't get the correct output, it's still blank!

Comment: var_dump($result); returns this: string(0) ""

Comment: Try adding the `CURLOPT_HEADER` option, to see what headers are coming back.

Comment: I just tried CURLOPT_USERPWD with a page on my site, and it worked perfectly. So it works.

Comment: Could it be that the program running at 27017 doesn't accept connections from localhost? Technically it is running on the same machine (both the php script and the program)

Comment: One of my friends mentioned that it might be expecting digest auth... time to try that once i figure it out how to do it :)

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST); - that was it. Works now.